# Google Lens Api/ Webscraping / SerpApi

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I checked several posts about google lens API. However, I was not able to come to a good conclusion. Google does not have a Lens API, but is clearly the best for visual search. I tried to scrape it but I was not successful yet.

```
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)

    # Locate the input field for file upload
    input_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")

    # Open the File Explorer to select the image using pyautogui
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'e')  # Open File Explorer (customize this shortcut based on your system)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Get the selected image path
    image_path = get_image_path()

    # Type the image path and press Enter using pyautogui
    pyautogui.write(image_path)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(1)

    # Copy the image path to the clipboard using pyperclip
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(1)

    # Click on the input field to activate it
    input_field.click()

    # Paste the image path from the clipboard into the input field using Ctrl+V
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

    # Submit the form or perform any necessary actions

    # Wait for the result page to load (adjust this time based on the page loading time)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Image uploaded successfully.")
```

I tried this code since if you are on the following URL
https://lens.google.com/search?p=0
you can copy and past a picture. However, I was not able to make it work and I am looking for a fast and good solution to it. Furthermore, I would like to know if it is legal to use google lens that way. Furthermore, be able to scrape it in headless mode.

I would like a clear answer regarding how to best scrape google lens and if it is possible and legal.